# Amusing bug involving Arabic usernames

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

In a [question which was put on hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846074/name-the-property-fx-ge-x), the last user named in the reviewers list of five has an Arabic username. Because of this (as far as I can tell), the number of hours ago that the post was closed was moved to the left hand side of the last name in the list (I guess because Arabic is a right-to-left language).

[image]

I doubt this behaviour was intended. It's also possible that it affects more than these lists of reviewers, though I can't recall any other examples of this happening.

Comment: It's not just Arabic, it's generally RTL languages, like Hebrew as well. I shall switch my user name to its Hebrew form just to show off! :-)

Comment: Is it a known bug then? I can't remember seeing this mentioned before, but then it would be a very low priority bug.

Comment: It's known to whoever writes in RTL languages often enough on the internet. :-)

Comment: Ah! I have very little experience, being an English-only speaker :).

Comment: Well, lucky you. It makes emailing with students nearly impossible!

Comment: @AsafKaragila That last part is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier: This depends very much on your approach. I encourage students to send me a lot of emails.

Comment: I'm going to do some research on this.

Comment: Any chance someone can show me a live link of this (or produce a live link)?

Comment: @DaveHaney http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/852499/edit/e7089abb-f00b-4137-9b25-4b11e90969bb the bug seems to disappear when the 'hours' turns into 'days' such as in the dropdown menu on this page http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/847552/edit/4003c651-f37d-455d-9b45-acbb50b08f11

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, this was a fun one. Thanks for bringing it to our attention! I've modified the display of usernames in Post status blocks and revision history to prevent this odd display. An additional change was made to the revision dropdown: the new format is `username - time - comments`. This will be live in the next release (> rev `2014.7.2.1690`).